# Any good(free/Open Source) sql query performance Analyzer tool

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, performance, analyzer

I am using sql server 2005 and i want to measure some query performance using an analyzer tool.... Any good tool (free/Open Source) that you can refer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28SQL.90%29.aspx) comes with SQL Server 2005 tools, and can be used to show resources used to perform a query/many queries.

As always, [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173%28SQL.90%29.aspx) (also from the tools) can be used to generate [execution plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and determine query performance.

***EDIT***
I'd like to also add this link to [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28SQL.90%29.aspx). I intended for this to be the link above, but I got my tabs confused :(

Answer (score 0):

[SQLProfiler](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/) for the express editions looks good (can't vouch for it myself, though, as I use the profiling tools that come with the enterprise edition: see Codesleuth's answer for more info).

Answer (score 0):

please see the below links :

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx

http://www.topshareware.com/ms-sql-query-analyzer/downloads/1.htm

maybe it is useful.